# Are duplicates of moms4mom.com questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, policy

For anyone that doesn't know, [moms4mom.com](http://moms4mom.com/) is a StackExchange 1.0 site about parenting - i.e. they're using very similar (but dated) software on very nearly the same topic.

[The general StackExchange rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) is that a question that can be easily answered by a "standard internet reference site" is a candidate for closing (a close reason that fits this is being added).  A "standard internet reference site" is subjective, of course, but a typical metric would be whether the site generally comes up in the first few search engine results for questions of that topic.  (Other metrics include quality, which ought to be high given the similar nature of the software).

If there's a question here that's an exact duplicate of one on moms4mom.com, do we want to vote it closed (ideally with a comment that references the other content), or are such questions acceptable here?

Comment: I refuse to believe that someone is harvesting questions from m4m just to score rep points, so I'll interpret this question only in terms of "do we want those questions duplicated here".

Comment: It may well happen once this site goes public.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think moms4mom.com can be called a reference site in any sense of the word. It's another Q&A site, so moms4mom.com questions are not off topic.

Comment: I agree; only close if the asker could have found it in 5 seconds with Google, or if it's clearly offtopic. Other parenting websites are not grounds for disqualification! I want to find all my (good, hard) questions answered *here*!

Comment: I think most SE users would consider a SE site a reference site.  Take a look at the venn diagram used to describe them - the reference part comes from the "wiki" elements.

Comment: @Tony, technically, Moms4Mom is no longer an SE site...

Comment: @benjol but it was, presumably retains essentially the same format, and so the comment still applies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because they could be being asked by Dads. In all seriousness, many of the fathers I know won't join up to any site with 'mums' in the name for fear of being torn apart in public when they say something that some mothers may consider dumb. Many of those sites are forums and we all know how flame wars on forums tend to lose the perspective of the original question and answer.

Comment: I remember I used M4M once or twice, and I found it pretty friendly, but I still had a dirty feeling because of the feminine name. That and the American spelling in the domain name really irritated me. That said, my wife hangs out on some parenting forums and god help any man who steps in there.

Comment: @Farseeker, @JBRWilkinson we in parenting.se may have the opposite problem of looking a bit too male. i was a bit depressed to see the Teaching Kids My Kids to Program question on day one.

Comment: ..that is most likely because of the StackOverflow.com heritage. As other subdomains start turning up top on search engines, the audience will widen.

Comment: @hawbsl Why is *THAT* question too male?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates of questions on M4M and similar sites should be allowed if the answer there is not what the OP is looking for. Include the link to the older question and explain briefly why the answer there was not what the OP needs.